# simple record and play application!

Tags: cocoa, audio

I am trying to make a simple application which will store the sound said by user , say on click of record button and will play it back to him/her , say on click of play button.

Can anyone suggest me some appropriate way to do this ??

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: The answer depends on the platform. Mac or iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QuickTime Kit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCocoaObjCKit/)'s capture APIs to record a movie of the audio, and QTMovie (from the same framework) to convert it to a more conventional format for audio files and to play back both the intermediate file and the converted file.

There used to be a QuickTime Kit Programming Guide, but it didn't cover capturing and is now gone from developer.apple.com. You should [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) against the docs.

This answer will work in a Cocoa (Mac) app. If you meant to ask about the iPhone, you should re-tag your question, as the solution will be completely different for a Cocoa app vs. a Cocoa Touch (iPhone) app.

Comment: hi Peter, thanks for your reply! I am developing it for Mac so your answer can prove to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used direct sound to create an entire internet phone application a few years ago.  Your question is far simpler, you won't have to deal with the circular buffer as critically.  Direct sound is pretty main stream and you can find a lot of help with it in forums, and it's free!