# Record audio in mac app

Tags: macos, audio-recording

I want to record an audio using my mac app & save it on my system. Please help me out !

Answer (score 0):

Q. [simple record and play application!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200871/simple-record-and-play-application)

QTKit framework: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004565

Comment: Please read the question properly.I want to record programmatically.Not using any external app

Comment: @Umar  the code for QTKit framework is not compiling.Can you please help me out.

Comment: @umar its compiling now.but they are making a movie.I just want audiorecording

Comment: @Umar can u please answer my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790008/audio-recorded-is-echoing-in-mac-app-using-apple-sample